# getting error while running any npm command

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

I am trying to install below module from last 4 days.

```
ionic,
cordova,
angular cli.
```

I am already using all version very smooth with zero issues but suddenly what happens everything breaks so,

I download node with 8.14.0 version. Installed successfully.

Tried in command prompt

```
node -v
8.14.0

npm -v
6.4.1
```

Next trying to install

```
npm install -g ionic cordova => Goes fails,
```

Trying separate command

```
npm install -g ionic => Installed successfully.

ionic -v
4.5.0

npm install -g cordova => Goes fails.
```

Another attempt.

```
npm install -g cordova@7.1.0 => installed.
```

Trying angular/cli

```
npm install -g @angular/cli => Goes fails.
```

- Trying all possible options with admin rights nothing changed.
- Trying with another system using a mac, getting an error.
- Clear cache in between of each command using `npm cache clear --force`

Here I am attaching some screenshot for reference.

[image]

[image]

A much unknown error comes randomly.

[Some logs are](http://keepnote.cc/53767033)

Thanks.

Comment: Have to try with as administrator?

Comment: What error you got while install cli ?

Comment: Yes.! @NishantDixit, Tried with admin already.

Comment: That was my internet connection issue. Why I don't known